# Swagger UI for messaging API

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I'd like to know if the following is possible.

Swagger is *almost* what I need to document a Message based API.  For instance for a [Command Message](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/CommandMessage.html) I'd like to say "Command" instead of "Post", and instead of "path" I'd like to have the name of the Command.

The [spec mentions](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#specification-extensions) that Vendor Extensions are possible using "x-" properties but I am 1) not finding any examples of how to do this and 2) not sure if the use of these properties would help me meet my goals.

Might anyone be able to point me to some resources that can help me move along?

Comment: Did you find an alternative to swagger for documenting your messaging apis?

Comment: No, sorry man.  All manual

Comment: Ouch! Thanks for the reply tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swagger is designed to document **REST** APIs which are based on **HTTP verbs**. You can't replace verbs or invent new ones.

Vendor extensions are there to allow adding additional information that the specification does not allow, but ultimately, it is still intended for REST APIs.

From what I gather, you're trying to describe something different.

We do welcome suggestions for additional roads for Swagger (that is, cover non-REST APIs), and in order to do that, I'd suggest opening an issue on the swagger-spec repository.

Comment: Thanks Ron, after doing a deep dive into the code I came to the same conclusion.

Comment: We are looking at the same thing.  Basically thinking of adding POST Controller endpoints that simply POST to message queues and put swagger on the fronting controller so documentation can be generated and you can POST messages through the queue.  Something like that...